# Data Annotation for Object Detection in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am working on deep learning problem, where I created annotations through labelImg over original images (jpgs). Also, I perform image augmentation since I am having very less data.
I performed operations like

1. Affine Translation
2. Image Brightness
3. Gaussian Blur
4. Horizontal Flip

When I am creating tf.record file it is only taking original image and its annotation file. It is not taking other augmented file into consideration.

Do I need to perform annotations on augmented images as well.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After few post reviews I found that annotation should be performed on all augmented images. Please note that annotations should be performed after train/test split so that later we don't need to manage files for doing correct train, test split.